# Check if a non-nullable field is null

Tags: python, django, django-models

I wanted to write some code like this:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    
    field = models.ForeignKey(SomeOtherModel)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.field is None:
            self.field = SomeOtherModel()

    ...
```

However this raises `self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist`. The Django code is very clear on that:

```
class ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor(object):

    def __get__(self, instance, instance_type=None):

        ...

        if val is None:
            # If NULL is an allowed value, return it.
            if self.field.null:
                return None
            raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist
```

An obvious workaround would be of course to make the field nullable however as far as I understand that would actually have an effect on the database schema, also I like the integrity checks Django offers. Another one would be to catch the exception and handle it appropriately. However this adds a lot of boilerplate code. Especially when there are multiple fields like that (a separate `try...except` block for each one of them - now that's ugly). What could I do?

I could use `initial` however this is quite limited when it comes to foreign keys. I do not always know the kind of default that I would like to have at the moment of creation. I will however know it at the initialization phase. Moreover it could then be dependent on the values of the other fields.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check if it has the attribute set -

```
if hasattr(self, 'field')
```

Answer (score 0):

proper way to refer a field in form is like this:
`self.fields['myfield']`
so, in your case, the null check should go like this
`self.fields['myfield'].value is None`

on the other note, don't use reserved/near to reserved words like 'field' for naming your fields.

Comment: I can't think of any meaningful sense in which the word 'field' is "reserved" in Python. In Python, objects are made up of attributes and methods.

Comment: nothing really breaks with 'field'. but I'm talking about DJango. Here form is having fields attribute and again using similar words to represent custom item make code confusing for other programmers. Good/Appropriate variable naming is always easy to read and understand.

Comment: That was just an example. In my actual model the field name is something totally different.